# Visual C++ Win32 takes a long time to start debugging after I press F5 or CTRL + F5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, visual-c++-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 professional update 5 on Windows 10. I have written a simple Hello World program listed below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I rebuild this code for Win32 (Debug or Release) and then run it without debugging (CTRL + F5), the console appears but it takes about 10 to 15 seconds before the "Hellow World" appears. If I run the code again, without rebuilding, the console with "Hello World" appears immediately. This only happens when I set the platform to "Win32", whereas the configuration could be "Debug" or "Release".

On setting the platform to "x64" everything works fine. That is the console with "Hello World" appears immediately both for "Debug" and "Release".

This problem is quite frustrating so any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware product and try again.  If it is Avast then get rid of it asap.